React Native Reanimated interpolateColor issue

I have a simple animated circular progress using react-native-svg and react-native-reanimated.
This is the AnimatedCircle
<Svg height={"90%"} width={"90%"} viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <AnimatedCircle
        animatedProps={animatedCircleProps}
        cx="50"
        cy="50"
        r="45"
        stroke="rgb(247, 30, 43)"
        strokeWidth="10"
        strokeDasharray={`${radius * Math.PI * 2}`}
        strokeLinecap="round"
    />
</Svg>

This is the animatedCircleProps used in the animatedProps
const animatedCircleProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    const interpolatedColor = interpolateColor(
        percentage.value,
        [0, 50, 100],
        [
            "rgb(247, 30, 43)",
            "rgb(255, 248, 48)",
            "rgb(32, 250, 45)",
        ],
    );

    return {
        stroke: interpolatedColor,
        strokeDashoffset: (1 - percentage.value / 100) * circumference,
    };
});

Using the value provided by interpolateColor always gives this error:
 ERROR  ReanimatedError: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap, js engine: reanimated

Is there something I'm missing? Isn't the value over here also a string? stroke="rgb(247, 30, 43)"
Why doesn't it work with the animatedCircleProps?

The values in interpolatedColor look fine (I just copied them and put in some animation I had and worked fine). A guess of mine would be that the thing that causes the error might be something in your component AnimatedCircle and you're using the values passed in animatedProps

@dianaqqq the AnimatedCircle is just using the Circle component from react-native-svg and created using Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);
